# Modeling gaussian random field with covariance cressie

Tags: r, spatial, modeling, gaussian

I'm trying to simulate a gaussian random field with covariance cressie (for non separable models that are shown [here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.56.1209&rep=rep1&type=pdf))

So I already have the function for my Cressie covariance and the data, but I haven't found a way to put into one of the functions for simulating gaussian random fields such like RandomFields because I need that my covariance to be a RMmodel.

```r
x=c(11.05,11.05,11.05,2.5,2.5,2.5,3.6,3.6,3.6,4.5,4.5,4.5,6.7,6.7,6.7,7.6,7.6,7.6,7.9,7.9,7.9,8.9,8.9,8.9,9,9,9,4,4,4,3.4,3.4,3.4)
y=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,6,6,6,5,5,5,7,7,7,8,8,8,9,9,9,3.5,3.5,3.5,7,7,7,4,4,4)
t=c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3)
z=c(22,26,35,44,53,42,21,15,26,37,56,69,76,74,42,26,15,14,23,37,48,57,54,61,16.8,27.4,39.1,23,35,48.57,21.14,35.6,17.1)

coordenada=data.frame(x,y)
rezagos_esp=as.matrix(dist(coordenada))
rezagos_temp=as.matrix(dist(t))
CH_1=function(h,u,p){(p[1]^2/((p[2]^2*u^2+1)))*exp(-(p[3]^2*h^2)/(p[2]^2*u^2+1))}
p=c(1,1,1)
CH_1(rezagos_esp,rezagos_temp,p)
```

So how can I generate a gaussian random field with the data that I already have?

Comment: Have you tried any of the `RandomFields` functions? Is there one that looks like it could/should work but doesn't?

Comment: @jsta, I did tried with the randomFields packages but there are no covariance function like this. And for a gaussian random field, I had to put a RF function or formula but there is no way to transform a formula to that.